# Change The Adapter when Click On Spinner

Tags: android, onclick, spinner, adapter

I need to change the Adapter of my Spinner exactly at the moment when I click on it.

I'm trying to display a Spinner with The value "Make Your choice" and then when the user click, another adapter is loaded on the Spinner and he can make his choice (without displaying the "Make Your choice").

Here is my code

```
ArayAdapter adapterclasse = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, affp.classes);
ArrayAdapter adaptermodule = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, affp.matiers);
spinner.setAdapter(adapterclasse);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        spinner.setAdapter(adaptermodule);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

but it's not working. When the app is launched, I got the second adapter loaded instead of the first.

Please help and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The second adapter is set because when the spinner is loaded the method onItemSelected is called, that's normal (the first element is selected).

Anyway, in general I don't think you need 2 adapters, you can just put "Make Your choise" on top and onItemSelected if the user has selected that, you can stop him and ask to select a real value.

Comment: Yeah this is what i was thinking about
but is there another way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's possible to load a new adapter when the user touch the view (spinner)

```
spinner.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{      
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        spinner.setAdapter(adapterclasse2);
        return false;
    }

});
```